# Constructuing vector equation question

Tags: vectors

I'm working on a three-part vector problem where a given straight line has a vector equation of

$$r = ( i + 3 j ) + \lambda( -i - j )$$

which I rearranged to get

$$r  = (1 - \lambda) i + (3 - \lambda) j$$

For the first part I had to show  the point (1,2) does not lie on this line, so I did

1 - $\lambda$ = 1 so $\lambda$ = 0 and

3 - $\lambda$ = 2 so $\lambda$ = 1

so $(1,2)$ does not lie on the line r, is this right? And if someone could give a more detailed explanation as to why/why not or a better way to set it out I'd love to hear it.

For the second part I have to construct a vector equation for a line that does go through  the point (1,2) and is perpendicular to r, so I  figured I'd try

$$s = ( i + 2 j ) + (\mu)( i - j )$$

$$s = (1 +\mu) i + (2 - \mu)j$$

Does this look like it would make s and r vectors perpendicular? Also I know that if the dot product of the two equations is 0 then they are perpendicular, but how would I go about multiplying the lines r and s? Do I have to substitute values in for lambda and mu, and if so which ones?

Finally for the third part I have to determine the point of intersection between the two lines r and s, how would I be able to do this? Any help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The 'better term' you're lacking is "rearranged"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first part is just fine.

You will not be finding the dot product of the lines $r$ and $s$ in the second part, but rather, of their "direction vectors," namely: $-i-j$ and $i-j.$ Note that $\lambda$ and $\mu$ don't come into play at all here. They are simply parameters that generate the lines from the starting vectors by multiples of the direction vectors.

As for the third part, try solving the system of equations $$1-\lambda=1+\mu\\3-\lambda=2-\mu$$ for $\lambda$ and $\mu,$ then confirm that this gets you the same point on both $r$ and $s.$

Comment: Thanks for the response! I managed to show that r.s = 0 and found out the values for λ=-1/2 and μ=1/2. Would the point of intersection be a combination of those two, or the values I get from the i and j equation components after I sub in the values?

So for 1 - λ = 1 + μ I get 1/2 on both sides and for 3 − λ = 2 −  μ I get 5/2. Would the point of intersection be (1/2 , 5/2)?

Comment: Exactly right! Well done.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for your help! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

The dot product of two *vectors* is zero when they are perpendicular; and when dealing with lines you should be looking at the *direction vectors*.  For your original line $r$, the direction vector was $-i-j$, and for your line $s$, the direction vector is $i-j$; so those are the things you should dot.

An equation for a line needs an independent variable, which is what your $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are.  (You might be accustomed to seeing $t$ there, but any variable will do.)

To find the intersection point, set the i-components equal and the j-components equal and see what you get. (Your variables are $\lambda$ and $\mu$, as mentioned above.) Plugging them in to their respective equations should give one (i.e. the same) point.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

$r=(1-\lambda)i+(3-\lambda)j$=$xi+yj$ .....(let)
The point (1,2) does not lie on the line if $x= 1$ & $y=2$ or $(1-\lambda)=1$ & &$(3-\lambda)=2$ or $\lambda=0$ & also $\lambda=1$ both the values of $\lambda$
are not same hence point (1,2) can't be on the line

for second part taking dot product of r & s zero then we find

[$(1-\lambda)i+(3-\lambda)j$][$(1+\mu)i+(2-\mu)j$]=0

$(1-\lambda)$ $(1+\mu)$+$(3-\lambda)$ $(2-\mu)$=0

$7-2\mu-3\lambda=0$

$\mu=\left(\frac{7-3\lambda}{2}\right)$ so $(1+\mu)=1+\left(\frac{7-3\lambda}{2}\right)$=$\left(\frac{9-3\lambda}{2}\right)$  & $ (2-\mu)=\left(\frac{3(\lambda-1)}{2}\right)$

using this in 's' we get

$s=\left(\frac{9-3\lambda}{2}\right)i+\left(\frac{3(\lambda-1)}{2}\right)j$

now for the point of intersection equating the coefficients of $i$ & $j$ of $r$ & $s$ we get two equations 
$\left(\frac{9-3\lambda}{2}\right)=(1-\lambda)$

on solving we get $\lambda=7$

& $\left(\frac{3(\lambda-1}{2}\right)=(3-\lambda)$

on solving we get $\lambda=\left(\frac{9}{5}\right)$

Hence the point of intersection is $(7,\frac{9}{5})$

IF ANY CORRECTION MOST WELCOME

Comment: You have solved to get that $\lambda=7$ **and** that $\lambda=\frac95.$ This should tell you something is wrong. Namely, you took the incorrect dot product in the second part, which then led to your contradictory conclusion in the third part after you changed to the erroneous form for the line $s.$ See my answer for a correct approach.

Comment: @ cameron Buie I m so sorry i just see your answer definitely a major mistake. can u plz help in deleting my answer I am not able now to do this.